# Certain Parts of SVG not showing

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I've got a bit of an issue with SVG files now. I'm trying to make the logo on my site set to an SVG, and now that it's live, my friends can see it (mobile browsers, safari) but I'm on Iridium (Chrome) and don't see it. I've tried Chrome on mobile, I've tried Brave (which I believe is also based on Chrome) and neither have worked. IE and Firefox (Quantum) do display the file with no issues, but only part of it displays on any chrome-based browser.

Here's a screenshot of what I see on chrome:
https://i.gyazo.com/8912785d57756c5cda09c941f4fa3542.png

Here's a screenshot of what I should see (Firefox):
https://i.gyazo.com/57272d67a4406243f6ea1aeeb89d7138.png

Some extra details.

-The text part is an image, and so is the girl. The rectangle that does show in Chrome is an actual rectangle. Like, it was the shape path when exported from Photoshop.

-When I open the image in chrome (just the image, not embedded on the site) it shows up fine. I can play with dimensions, do whatever and everything works perfectly.

-The SVG size is all 100% everywhere, and the parent div is the size I need it to be, so that's not the problem. I'm not that new to embedding SVGs I use a number of them on the site as well.

-There's no error in the browser console, not that I'm sure it would make one either way.

EDIT: Included code:
https://hastebin.com/fugodijiwa.xml

Comment: and what if you share tou code ? it will be easier to see the issue

Comment: I know it's not an issue with the code because I can load it standalone without embedding, but sure.

Comment: Report Chrome bugs to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)

Comment: Note that what you are doing (merge two png images in an svg file) is a bit useless...

Comment: Help is going to be very limited without seeing a [mcve]. Pictures of something failing are not anywhere near as useful as being able to test the real thing.

Comment: Is your site hosted on a web server (ie. http/https)? Or are you testing locally (file://)?  If you are doing the latter, then try the former.